# Recovering GPG keys from a backup directory

Tags: gpg

I have a backup image mounted at `/mnt`. I need to recover (and revoke) a key in the secret keyring on this backup.

How can I list keys and generate a revocation key for a key stored in this other keyring?

When I do:

```
gpg --homedir /mnt/home/naftuli/.gnupg --list-keys
```

I see the keys installed locally and not the keys installed in the backup's keyring.

What's *really* strange is that if I `chroot` to the `/mnt` folder and run `gpg --list-keys`, I **still** see the keys in the other keyring.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `HOME=/mnt/home/naftuli/ gpg --list-keys`?

Comment: Same thing. It shows the results from the other keyring. One of the keys was just generated today, and the backup is from 2013/11/29, so the new key _really_ shouldn't be in that backup.

Comment: do you have any absolute paths in /mnt/home/naftuli/.gnupg/gpg.conf? what does `ls -lnd /mnt/home/naftuli/ /home/naftuli/` say?

Comment: You probably have gpg-agent running, and are listing keys in the agent. Try `--no-use-agent`

Comment: Looks like something weird was going on, the mounted directory was a loop for some reason to /. No idea why, but working around it.

Comment: @derobert gpg-agent stores secret keys only. `gpg --list-keys` doesn't affect secret keys. The man page says about `--no-use-agent`: 'This is dummy option. gpg2 always requires the agent.'

Answer (score 1):

no need to chroot, I often generate wot maps / diagrams from a separate gpg db than my main, (for example a work team). to do this export GNUPGHOME

```
export GNUPGHOME=/mnt/home/naftuli
cd $GNUGPHOME
gpg --list-keys
```

Answer (score 0):

If chrooting, killing the agent, etc. don't work for you,
swap the gpg folders, and reboot.

If you *still* see your new keys, something isn't right in your setup, or the folder paths are not what you think they are.